# Toggle button type property with OnsenUI / AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to make some toggle buttons with OnsenUI.  I just want the toggle states to be represented by the ons-button property button type="" (normal) or type="quiet".

The logic seems quite straightforward, a plunkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/25Y9KSfSv2Ket5gHzcjI?p=preview, with the html below:

```
<ons-button 
    type="{{buttonType()}}"
    ng-click="!bool"
    >
    button type {{buttonType()}}
</ons-button>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.bool = false;

  $scope.buttonType = function() {
    if ($scope.bool) {
      return ''; //normal button
    } else {
      return 'quiet';  //quiet button
    }
  }    

});
```

I have tried toggling with ng-class, however, same problem; the button does not update once initially rendered on the page (and apparently is not updating with any digest updates).

Naturally, I initially tried this using checkboxes, however I could not escape the 300ms click delay on mobile devices. (I know OnsenUI uses Fastclick, but it seems to do nothing on Android at all, and on iOS checkboxes are still slow, so I'm trying toggle buttons and actually may prefer this method if it will work.)

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't actually changing the value of `$scope.bool` on that `ng-click`. You should do `ng-click="bool = !bool"`. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/08sgrG57yym82l6WSDrO?p=preview

Comment: Ahh yes, that was dumb, it's a simplification of my actual code (which does actually change the scope variable). Thanks for pointing that out. Nonetheless, I notice the type="" isn't updating when the scope variable is updated. The button properties seem to be bound to the page upon loading the view and immutable for the life of the view.

Comment: I should have noticed there was something more. I don't have experience with onsen-ui, so I couldn't say if what you want is possible, but worst-case scenario you could have two buttons and switch between one or the other.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am also looking at adding the button styling to a standard html button, where the properties are more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this was outside the functionality of the custom button directive.

I used a standard html button with 2 css classes; resembling topcoat-button and topcoat-button--quiet, and used ng-class to switch between them.